# Write dictionary values to csv python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have dictionary,

```
d = [{
       'id': 1
       'a' : [11,12],
       'b' : [25,17],
       'c' : [13,18] 
}]
```

Here I want to write in csv with column headers as keys (id,a,b,c)
and values as rows.
Here I want to write first row has values (1,11,25,13) with keys (id,a,b,c)
and second row will have values (1,12,17,18) with the same keys having id same for both rows.
Meaning if my value has more than two values it needs to be written in csv in next row with same columns headers and same id.

I was trying something like this

```
CSV ="\n".join([k+','+",".join(v) for k,v in dict_data[0].items()])
print CSV
```

But again, the columns are coming as row,
csv file 
id,1,(no value, i need 1 here)        ---- Here id will not appear
a,11,12
b,25,17
and they are coming as rows, i want id, a b as columns

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: will your `id` key always be an `int`, or can it also be a `list` object? How regular is your data?

Comment: You can either use **string manipulation** to write a `.csv`, or use a library such as `pandas` that have methods that write `.csv` file, corresponding to your datas (you will need to format your data according to `pandas` of course).

Comment: Did you try to "transpose" the input data and use `csv` library?

Answer (score 2):

I think Pandas DataFrame is your best shot. I have slightly modified your data to make id column as a list too -

```
d = {
       'id': [1],
       'a' : [11,12,13],
       'b' : [25,17],
       'c' : [13,18] 
}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').transpose()
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
print(df)
```

Finally, just output it to a csv
`df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`

Output -

```
id     a     b     c
0  1.0  11.0  25.0  13.0
1  1.0  12.0  17.0  18.0
2  1.0  13.0  17.0  18.0
```

It first creates a dataframe with NA values for missing and then replaces those NA values with the values in the previous row.

Comment: List has no attribute values this is what I get

Answer (score 0):

Try `from_dict` for dataframe creation of `pandas` after converting `id` to a `list`:

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{ 'id': 1,
       'a' : [11,12],
       'b' : [25,17],
       'c' : [13,18] }]

# d['id'] = [d['id']] * len(d['a'])  # no need for this line; kept only because it is discussed in comments
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d[0])  # if dict is in a list, use d[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c  id
0  11  25  13   1
1  12  17  18   1
```

To write to csv file:

```
df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hey,firstly the values can can be string.

Comment: No, it will still work: `["5"] * 5` produces `['5', '5', '5', '5', '5']`. The list items are repeated, not arithmetically multiplied.

Comment: Actually, this code statement is not needed. The output remains same even if this statement is omitted.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply.Yes Dict is list, i used index[0]
but having error arrays must all be same length

Comment: It works ok for me. There should be a comma after "1" .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame` contructor with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(d[0], columns=['id','a','b','c'])
print (df)
   id   a   b   c
0   1  11  25  13
1   1  12  17  18
```

and then:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

---

All together:

```
pd.DataFrame(d[0], columns=['id','a','b','c']).to_csv(file, index_col=False)
```

Comment: Hey , values can be string  as well.

Comment: Error while using code I get is arrays must all be same length

Comment: Problem is with sample data or real data dictionary?